# python cx_Freeze askopenfile

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze, filedialog

Following file (Python 3.7) does everything it is supposed to do. When I press the “Open file” button it opens “askopenfilename” dialog.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import messagebox
from os import path

class GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        self.win=tk.Tk()
        self.create_widgets()

    def exitfcn(self):
        result = tk.messagebox.askquestion('Warning', 'Exit?')      
        if result == 'yes':
            self.win.destroy()

    # Button callback
    def getFileName(self):
        self.fDir = path.dirname(__file__)
        self.fname=fd.askopenfilename(parent=self.win, initialdir=self.fDir)
        if self.fname != '':
            self.getFile(self.fname)

    def getFile(self, file):
        print(self.fname)

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.mainButtons=ttk.Frame(self.win)
        self.mainButtons.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=100, pady=200)

        # Adding a Button - Open file
        self.openFilebtn=ttk.Button(self.mainButtons, text='Open file', command=self.getFileName)
        self.openFilebtn.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=20)

        # Adding a Button - Exit
        self.exitbtn=ttk.Button(self.mainButtons, text='Exit', command=self.exitfcn)
        self.exitbtn.grid(column=0, row=1)

gui = GUI()
gui.win.mainloop()
```

When I use cx_Freeze (5.1.1) with following setup file:

```
import os
import sys
from tkinter import filedialog
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

build_exe_options={
        'packages':['tkinter', 'tkinter.filedialog', 'os'],
        'include_files':[
        os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
        os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),]
            }

base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

executables=[Executable("dialog_test.py", base=base)]

setup(name='dialog_test',
version=0.1,
description='Test file for cx_Freezer',
options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
executables=executables
)
```

“Exit” button works, “Open file” button doesn’t open “askopenfilename” dialog. Where can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could try using [`pyinstaller`](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) instead of `cx_freeze` to create the frozen application. When I freeze your script with `pyinstaller`, it creates a frozen application with a properly working file-open dialog.

You can install the `pyinstaller` package through `pip`:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

and afterwards you can create the frozen application with just the command:

```
pyinstaller dialog_test.py
```